# VS Code - using HTML extensions in another language

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, mako

is there any option to work in mako templates (based on HTML it is something like Flask but very old) and use all extensions from HTML? I installed mako templates extension but that is just for a syntax highlighting. 
I used to work in Atom and there was a extension which uses both of languages.

*For examaple: see hints while writting bootstrap classes col-something etc.*

So far Iam using this:

`"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "mako": "html"
    }`

I can use Emmet Abbrevation but that is all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

**Adding a file extension to a language**

You can add new file extensions to an existing language with the files.associations setting.

For example, the setting below adds the .myphp file extension to the php language identifier:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.myphp": "php"
}
```

See more: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview

Comment: associate file doesnt help becouse I need mako higlighting. If i do it everything in .mako is just a HTML code and I also lose mako extension becouse It is interpreted as a HTML.

I need something like "*.mako": "mako, html"